# Use the function css() of jQuery on NodeJS

Tags: jquery, css, node.js, request, cheerio

I'm currently using NodeJS to scrap a web page with the following modules: Cheerio and Request

Is it possible to use the css() jQuery function in NodeJS ?

```
request({uri: website}, function(error, response, body) {

  var $ = cheerio.load(body);
  myItemColor = $('.myitem').css('color');
  console.log(myItemColor);

});
```

I would like to retrieve a css property of a given jQuery object.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

But you need to run jQuery inside a DOM so that this works. Check out my [jQuery on the server sample](https://github.com/goloroden/node-samples/tree/master/jquery/01%20using-jquery-on-the-server), especially [this part of the app.js file](https://github.com/goloroden/node-samples/blob/master/jquery/01%20using-jquery-on-the-server/app.js#L39-L77) to see how you can use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to create a server-side DOM for a download HTML site.

PS: I haven't tried it, but it should work with the `css` function as well (I don't see any reason why it shouldn't).

Comment: If this solved it, please a) mark it as answer, and b) up-vote it, please. Thanks :-)!